# iOS - Set CollectionView Header with dynamic height

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with a Header and no cells.

I've set the header size to be equal to the superview bounds as following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

This header has a `UITextView` in it, which is anchored, as well, to the headers bounds (topAnchor, leftAnchor, bottomAnchor and rightAnchor).

I need the header to be anchored to the collection view height when the keyboard is closed, but anchored to the top of the keyboard when this one is opened, changing its size respectively.

The problem here lies when the text of the headers `UITextView` subview keeps growing and the text goes behind the keyboard.

Here's a GIF showing what's happening.
The yellow view is the Header
The white view is the TextView with some padding.

When I pass the keyboard the text goes behind it - if I could anchor the header to the bottom of the screen when there's no keyboard and to the bottom of the keyboard when its shown would be great.

[image: gif]

Any hint?
Thanks

### EDIT ADICIONAL INFO

As @Aravind said I've implemented the Notification listener to fire whenever the keyboard shows or hides.

Since I'm using the `UITextView` inside the Header class as its subview I've implemented the following:

This is an helper function to anchor my views easily:

```
extension UIView {
func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, paddingTop: CGFloat, paddinfLeft: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingRight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if let top = top {
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
    }
    if let left = left {
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddinfLeft).isActive = true
    }
    if let bottom = bottom {
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
    }
    if let right = right {
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
    }
    if width != 0 {
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    }
    if height != 0 {
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    }
}
}



override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(inputTextView)
    inputTextView.delegate = self

    inputTextView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddinfLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 0)

    setupInputTextViewToolbar()


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
        object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
        object: nil)
}
```

Then the Show/Hide functions

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ sender:NSNotification){
    guard let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
    inputTextView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddinfLeft: 12, paddingBottom: keyboardSize.height, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 0)
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ sender:NSNotification){
        self.inputTextView.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddinfLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

The show function works properly and makes the text view to the remaining screen size so it doesn't stay behind the keyboard, so far so good.

But when I fire the hide function it doesn't resize again to the bottom of the screen.

What maybe causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here make an outlet of the textView's bottom constraint and change its value when keyboard shows up and when it hides like,

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
            object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
            object: nil)

}

   func keyboardWillShow(_ sender:NSNotification){

        let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        bottomSpace.constant = (keyboardSize?.height)!


    }
    func keyboardWillHide(_ sender:NSNotification){
    bottomSpace.constant = 0
   }
```

Comment: Nice tip. I'll try it out and I'll feedback you

Comment: WOW. this was a really smart way to do it. thank you very much for this info. I'd never remember to add an observer to keep 'an eye' when the keyboard would appear or dismiss to re-edit the text view bottom padding. that was super clever. thank you one more time

Comment: somehow the text view bottom padding works properly when the keyboard is being presented but it does not pad back to 0 when it dismisses. I'm adding more adicional code to the info so you can see

Comment: I've updated the question with your code in it. Can you see what's causing the Hide function not to resize the `UITextView` ?

Comment: I might create another question regarding this new issue. Anyway your tip was great :)

Comment: Ok post the link of the question as comment here.
Just try self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after  self.inputTextView.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddinfLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 0)